# Check database exists in Mongodb using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

how can I put an exceptional handling for checking whether database is exists or not in mongodb using pymongo.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used PyMongo but you could list all the available databases (with the comment listDatabases) and check if your database is returned. Check also this link: https://gist.github.com/david-torres/8450526

Answer (score 20):

An attempt to access a database that doesn't exist is not considered an error. Instead, the database will be created if it doesn't exist when you first write to it.

So if you need to know whether a database already exists, you need to explicitly check. You can call [`list_database_names()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.database_names) on your `MongoClient` object to get a list of the existing database names:

```py
client = MongoClient()
dbnames = client.list_database_names()
if 'mydbname' in dbnames:
    print "It's there!"
```